# how to Get id value from SEO URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

i am trying to get id value from URL in php  this is SEO URL

```
http://www.travelhome.co.in/domestic-tour-itinerary/54/amarnath-yatra-by-road-pahalgam
```

i want to get 54 in to $id like `$id=54`

and i already tried

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);
$link = $urlArray[1];
$id = $urlArray[2];
```

Comment: Hi, what is your exact question ? what is the problem with the current code ? If you want to get help, please be as explicit as you can so other members don't waste time on a solution that does not fit your need.

Comment: What's the meaning of "i want to get 54 in to $id"?

Comment: $id = $urlArray[4]; or $id = $urlArray[3]; ?

Comment: oscar please see the URL and you will understand

Comment: @Asesha George: there is no $urlArray, it is $uriArray, see your code: `$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);`

Comment: ok i changed to uriarray still not working do i required to do any thing in .htaccess

Comment: hellcode you are correct is uriarray but its woking on $id = $uriArray[2]; thank you for your help

Comment: @hellcode Please answer the question instead of making a comment so the question could be closed. Thanks! (The problem is what he told you, you are using wrong variable names)

Comment: yes i did.  thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
$str = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: and then you can get the id by using echo $matches[0][0];

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);
$link = $uriArray[1];
$id = $uriArray[2];
```

and in .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^domestic-tour-itinerary/(.*)/(.*)$ domestic-tour-itinerary/?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

i got $id=54 from url